# MAC no longer authenticates with IIS7 using NTLM but does with IIS6

Tags: macos, authentication, safari, iis-7.5, ntlm

I recently upgraded my Intranet web server to Server 2008 x64 running IIS 7.5. The staff website that I maintain uses NTLM to tell which user is viewing the page and display appropriate content based on that. Since the upgrade or MAC clients can no longer connect through Safari and Firefox is no longer accepting the about:config setting of network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris. I had to remove the FQDN from that entry for them to not get the 401 page only.

My development server is still a Server 2003 box with IIS6 and the MACs can authenticate to that both through Safari and firefox with no problems.

I checked on the new IIS7 server for the registry key LmCompatibilityLevel located in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa but this key is not there. So my understanding is that it will result in level 0 by default allowing LM, NTLM and NTLM v2 auth requests.

Any suggestions on how to get authentication back?

Comment: There's no such thing as a MAC client. Do you mean Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with Safari forcing users to login innumerable times and this fixed it for me:

In IIS Manager (IIS 7), navigate to the website and right-click on Authentication to "Open feature". 
Right-click on "Windows Authentication" and select "Providers" which should display Negotiate & NTLM
Remove "Negotiate" and restart the website and it should work with a single login prompt.

Comment: I will check that out as soon as I can.